# I want to place file contents written per line with a special symbol defined in string /URL taken from console in Ruby

Tags: ruby, net-http

I am trying to write a simple fuzzer in Ruby which will take values from a text file line by line and these values are replaced with a symbol $fuzz$ in GET URL parameter entered by user from console.

I have wrote code like this:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI(gets())

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
  response = http.request request 
  puts response.body
end
```

I am confused how can I replace the symbol $fuzz$ given by user from console in GET request with file contents per line one by one.

like first line of file is ' or 1=1 and I want to replace $fuzz$ symbol written in some GET request /item.php?id=$fuzz$ with this line content from file and then want to fire these request.

For example I take URL form console say example.com/item.php?id=fuzz, now I open one file having several lines. I want to edit this URL taken from console again with "fuzz" word replaced with file line one by one and want to send these URL requests with file content replaced to word fuzz in GET request parameter and then want to store all responses in new file.

Comment: this is a little too abstract for me -- can you flush out with  a more concrete example?

Comment: For example I take URL form console say http://www.example.com/item.php?id=fuzz, now I open one file having several lines. I want to edit this URL taken from console again with "fuzz" word replaced with file line one by one and want to send these URL requests with file content replaced to word fuzz in GET request parameter and then want to store all responses in new file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to split this up into two classes

```
require 'net/http'

class FileIdExtractor
  def ids_from_file(path_to_file)
    file = File.open(path_to_file) or die "Unable to open file..."
    content_array=[]
    file.each_line {|line| contentArray.push line }
    content_array
  end
end

class UrlToFile
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def write_content_to_file_for_id(id, doc)
    local_filename = "/tmp/#{id}.html"
    File.open(local_filename, 'w') {|f| f.write(doc) }
  end

  def get_html_content_from_id(id)
    full_url = @url + id
    open(full_url).read
  end

end

# to run it, something like
puts "What is the URL. use format http://example.com/item.php?id="
url = gets
ids = FileIdExtractor.new.ids_from_file("your-file-path")
ids.each do |id|
  url = UrlToFile.new(url)
  doc = url.get_html_content_from_id(id)
  url.write_content_to_file_for_id(id, doc)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for help but I want to do all these for any URL I take from console using gets() having "fuzz" string in any parameter and then want to replace this fuzz word in URL request with file contents, each line of file once and then want to fire this request again with replaced content and then want to store new responses in new file.

Comment: Just add an initializer to UrlToFile for your base URL path.

Comment: Still not able to get you, I am confused a lot , please tell me how can I use that Initializer in UrlToFile class. I guess it is like making file variable instance variable, something like this @file = File.open(path_to_file) or die "Unable to open file..."

Comment: @AkashPanchal updated the code sample to get value from user, store it and send into UrlToFile. Note: if you're not sure what this is doing, you should start learning ruby with something far, far simpler.